# What does $ K^{\alpha}$ mean?

Tags: notation, field-theory, galois-theory

This is in context of a statement in galois theory:

If $F \subseteq K \subseteq L$ and $K$ is splitting over $F$, then $K^{\alpha}=K$ for each $\alpha \in Aut(L)$.

Comment: I really am not sure what "$\;K\;$ splitting over $\;F\;$" means (perhaps that $\;K\;$ is a splitting field of a set of polynomials in $\;F[x]\;$ ?), but I think $\;K^\alpha\;$ means the fixed field of the automorphism $\;\alpha\;$ .

Comment: Yeah I think it means $K$ is the splitting field over $F$ of some polynomial $f \in F[x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From context, it appears that $K^\alpha$ denotes $\alpha(K)$, i.e. the image of $K$ under the map $\alpha:L\to L$.